# Add a day with javascript

Tags: javascript

can you please help me to correct this :

```
function ajout()
{
   var date_init = document.getElementById("actual").value;
   var date_nmbr = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
   var date_resu = addDaysToDate(date_init, date_nmbr);
   document.getElementById("result").value = date_resu;
   return(true);
}

<input type="text" name="actual" id="actual"><br>
<input type="text" name="result" id="result"><br>
<input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" onChange="javascript:ajout();">
```

Cordialy

Comment: Make sure you let the SO community know what is going wrong.  *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself."*

Comment: What is the error you're getting?  What have you tried?  Is `addDaysToDate` your code, and can you post it?